# Get rid of the dot at the end of cventry and of the pagenumber in komacv

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I want to get rid of the dot after \cventry. I found the section in the cls-file but if I copy that in my preamble and remove the dot it still doesn’t work. Only if I remove the dot temporarily in the cls-File it works. I think this is something for the renewecommand – but I haven’t been able to apply it to get the result…

I actually don’t see why the dot and also the commas between the parts of \cventry are pre-formatted. Wouldn’t it be better to keep the style flexibel?

```
\documentclass[style=casual,]{komacv}
\renewcommand*\urlbordercolor{red}
\hypersetup{pdfcreator=Someone else}

\providecommand*{\cventry}[7][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
{\bfseries#3}%
\ifstrempty{#4}{}{, {\itshape#4}}%
\ifstrempty{#5}{}{, #5}%
\ifstrempty{#6}{}{, #6}%
.% That is the dot I want to get rid of.
\ifx&#7&%
\else{%
  \newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
    \small#7%
  \end{minipage}%
}%
\fi%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{1835--1838}{Homeschooling}{}{Gateshead}{grades 1--3}{Teacher:    Mr.~NN, under supervision of my aunt Ms. Reed.}
\cventry{1838--1844}{Lowood School}{}{Lowood}{grades 3--8}{A charitable institution under the guidance of Mr.~Brocklehurst.}




\end{document}
```

With the pagenumbers I also found the entry in the komacv_casual.sty-File. But I could not undo it in the preamble. The relevant code is:

```
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark/\totalpagemark}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep address and others in the foot?

Comment: Yes. That is the thing – I just want to get rid of the pagenumber.

Answer (score 2):

That should do what you want: *renew* the definition ov `cventry` as well as the definition of the pagestyle:

```
\documentclass[style=casual,]{komacv}
\renewcommand*\urlbordercolor{red}
\hypersetup{pdfcreator=Someone else}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifstrempty{#4}{}{, {\itshape#4}}%
        \ifstrempty{#5}{}{, #5}%
        \ifstrempty{#6}{}{, #6}%
        % That is the dot I want to get rid of.
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{%
            \newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
                \small#7%
            \end{minipage}%
        }%
        \fi%
    }%
}
  \defpagestyle{footer}
  {{}{}{}}% head definition (empty)
  {% foot definition
    {}{}% definition for twoside layout
    {% definition for oneside layout
      \hspace*{\fill}%
      \parbox{\@footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{@addresscolor}\usekomafont{addressfont}%
        \ifdefempty{\addressstreet}{}{%
          \addtofooter[]{\@addresssymbol\addressstreet}%
          \ifdefempty{\addresscity}{}{%
            \addtofooter[~--~]{\addresscity}}}%
        \ifdefempty{\mobile}{}{%
          \addtofooter{\@mobilesymbol\mobile}}%
        \ifdefempty{\phonenr}{}{%
          \addtofooter{\@phonesymbol\phonenr}}
        \ifdefempty{\faxnr}{}{%
          \addtofooter{\@faxsymbol\faxnr}}%
        \ifdefempty{\email}{}{%
          \addtofooter{\@emailsymbol\emaillink{\email}}}
        \ifdefempty{\homepage}{}{%
          \addtofooter{\@homepagesymbol\httplink{\homepage}}}%
        \ifdefempty{\extrainfo}{}{%
          \addtofooter{\extrainfo}}\@flushf%
      }% Ende parbox
%      \hspace*{\fill}%
%      \makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark/\totalpagemark}
    }% end definition onesided layout
  }% end footer definition
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom

\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{1835--1838}{Homeschooling}{}{Gateshead}{grades 1--3}{Teacher:    Mr.~NN, under supervision of my aunt Ms. Reed.}
\cventry{1838--1844}{Lowood School}{}{Lowood}{grades 3--8}{A charitable institution under the guidance of Mr.~Brocklehurst.}



\end{document}
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you so much! The \makeatletter makes it possible to apply the renewcommand, right? Obviously I still have a lot to learn…

Comment: @PeterStrawson [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351)